# Reverting Sublime Text 2 to a freshly installed state

Tags: sublime-text, reinstall

How can I revert Sublime Text 2 to a freshly installed state in Ubuntu 16.04? On searching, I got [this documentation.](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/revert.html) But it does not mention about Ubuntu. Any help?

Comment: Why don't you uninstall and then reinstall it? You may have to purge it to eliminate all config files, but you should be able also to delete them yourself in ~/.config/sublime-text-2/. You can also try to just delete that folder and start sublime again and see what happens.

Comment: There is no .config folder in ubuntu :(

Comment: However uninstalling and reinstalling is working as for now :)

Comment: Then I'll add it as the answer for future reference, please mark it as resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall and then reinstall it. You may have to purge it to eliminate all config files, but you should be able also to delete them yourself in `~/.config/sublime-text-2/`. You can also try to just delete that folder and start sublime again and see what happens.

Comment: Please note that I am on Ubuntu 16.04. There is no .config folder. Please add in the answer above  what the actual folder is. Thank you :)

Comment: @AnkitShubham I just tested in a 16.04 Ubuntu and there is a .config folder. If you are using Nautilus to browse to the files remember that all files and folders starting with a dot "." are hidden. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to show and hide hidden files. If you are on the command line you have to use `ls -a` to show all files, also the hidden ones.